# How to properly prevent 504 Gateway Time-out?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I've an script that can run for about 15 min as it is a large data migration tool.

I have the problem that either if i set `fastcgi_read_timeout 9900;` it never times out or if i set it to less then it times out before my script finished running.

EDIT: I have taken away the `fastcgi_read_timeout 9900;` from `nginx.conf` and setted  `max_execution_time = 1300;` in php.ini and I get a 504 Gateway Time-out now instead of looping forever.

How can I properly set that the page should be live until the script finishes executing?

Comment: `fastcgi_read_timeout` is the interval between [two successive read operations](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout) so if the response is fed progressively then the timer will reset after each read.

Comment: Then how can i increase the executiong time of my PHP script?

Comment: You can use [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in php.ini (or the pool settings if using PHP-FPM) or alternatively try plugging [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) at the beginning of the script / in the bootstrap.

Comment: I;ve done what you adviced and I get a timeout now

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to run this in the foreground?  While it's possible to hack at the config files long enough for you to get this behavior, it's a very fragile configuration.  Is this something that's actually outputting useful information to the user as it goes?  If not, this is almost certainly suited to a background task, rather then trying to run it in one request.

Even if this is outputting to the user, have you considered running it as a background task, and piping output to the user via some asynchronous method?

Comment: How would i run it on the background?